# How to represent regex number ranges (e.g. 1 to 12)?

Tags: regex, coding-style, standards

I'm currently using `([1-9]|1[0-2])` to represent inputs from 1 to 12. (Leading zeros not allowed.)

However it seems rather *hacky*, and on some days it looks **outright dirty**.

☞ Is there a **proper** in-built way to do it?

☞ What are some other ways to represent number ranges?

Comment: If "Bigger is better", then (1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12) would be better.

Comment: You need to wrap the expression with anchors, otherwise you will match the first digits of an erroneous value like `1234`. Something like this: `^([1-9]|1[0-2])$` or possibly: `\b([1-9]|1[0-2])\b` will work better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tend to go with forms like `[2-9]|1[0-2]?` which avoids backtracking, though it makes little difference here. I've been conditioned by XML Schema to avoid such "ambiguities", even though regex can handle them fine.

Comment: Basically, when the matcher sees a "1" character, the "meaning" is ambiguous until it sees more characters. Is it the "1" for [1-9] or the "1" for 1[0-2]? Regex doesn't care about meaning, but it's still sometimes an efficiency concern since the matcher has to keep both branches active until the ambiguity is resolved.

Comment: so you are saying in the eyes of the regex machine this is the fastest solution: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12 ?

Comment: No, I'm not comparing `[2-9]` with `2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9` -- don't know which is faster. I'm comparing `1|10` with `10?`. Not that it will make a matter for such a trivial example, but for more involved regexes, it will help to remove common prefixes of branches. Perhaps a better example: `ab|ac` improved to `a(b|c)`.

Comment: In my case, numbers under 10, should have a leading zero, so i changed the pattern as follows `0[1-9]|1[0-2]?`

Comment:  This expression also accepts numbers like 123, you can test it here https://regexr.com/5hjpc, the idea is to test only numbers from 1 - 12 not more not less

Comment: @DiegoAlbertoZapataHäntsch so, something like this: `/^([2-9]|1[0-2]?)$/`

Comment: @BobBrown it doesn't work you can test your expression in these links https://regexr.com/5hk0s and https://regexr.com/5hkae to confirm that it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the correct one:

```
[1-9]|1[0-2]
```

Otherwise you don't get the 10.

Comment: This will accept any number that does not have a 0 in it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the better answer, with exact match from 1 - 12.

```
(^0?[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$)
```

Previous answers doesn't really work well with HTML input regex validation, where some values like '1111' or '1212' will still treat it as a valid input.

Answer (score 5):

​​​​
You can use:

```
[1-9]|1[012]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
^[1-9]|10|11|12$
```

Matches 0-9 or 10 or 11 or 12. thats it, nothing else is matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
^[1-9]$|^[1][0-2]$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following pattern `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` use this which will return values from **1** to **12** (*January to December*) even if it initially starts with **0** (*01, 02, 03, ..., 09, 10, 11, 12*)

Answer (score 1):

The correct patter to validate numbers from 1 to 12 is the following:

```js
(^[1-9][0-2]$)|(^[1-9]$)
```

The above expression is useful when you have an input with type number and you need to validate month, for example. This is because the input type number ignores the 0 in front of any number, eg: 01 it returns 1.

You can see it in action here: https://regexr.com/5hk0s

if you need to validate string numbers, I mean, when you use an input with type text but you expect numbers, eg: expiration card month, or months the below expression can be useful for you:

```js
((^0[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$))
```

You can see it in action here https://regexr.com/5hkae

I hope this helps a lot because it is very tricky.

Regards.

Answer (score -3):

In **python** this matches any number **between 1 - 12**:

```
12|11|10|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1
```

The descending order **matters**. In ascending order **10**, **11** and **12** would match **1** instead as regex usually pick the **first matching value**.