# re.findall only finding half the patterns

Tags: python, pattern-matching, string-parsing

I'm using re.findall to parse the year and month from a string, however it is only outputting patterns from half the string. Why is this?

```
date_string = '2011-1-1_2012-1-3,2015-3-1_2015-3-3'

find_year_and_month = re.findall('[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[1-12]', date_string)

print(find_year_and_month)
```

and my output is this:

```
['2011-1', '2012-1']
```

This is the current output for those dates but why am I only getting pattern matching for half the string?

Comment: That `[1-12]` part is not doing what you think it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[1-12]` doesn't do what you think it does. It matches anything in the range `1` to `1`, or it matches a `2`.

See this question for some replacement regex options, like `([1-9]|1[0-2])`: [How to represent regex number ranges (e.g. 1 to 12)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105146/how-to-represent-regex-number-ranges-e-g-1-to-12)

If you want an interactive tool for experimenting with regexes, I personally recommend [Regexr](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your regex pattern as shown below:

```
import re

date_string = '2011-1-1_2012-1-3,2015-3-1_2015-3-3'    
find_year_and_month = re.findall('([1-2][0-9]{3}-(?:1[0-2]|[1-9]))', date_string)

print(find_year_and_month)
```

The output:

```
['2011-1', '2012-1', '2015-3', '2015-3']
```

Comment: Interesting thing: You should replace `(?:[1-9]|1[0-2]))` with `(?:1[0-2]|[1-9]))` because otherwise (accoring to my testing on regex101.com) a string like `2011-12-1` will only match the `2011-1` part and not `2011-12`. (I think this is why regex's are called _greedy_.) Seems like the first part of the `or` (represented by the pipe `|`) is evaluated, takes a minimal match and then does not evaluate the second option of the `or`. (Actually not sursprising, if you think about it.)

Comment: @Michael, see my update (for that case)

Comment: Yep. Even though I like the `[2-9]|1[0-2]?` given in the link presented in @sam's answer best. (Did not think of that possibility myself.)